# Issues defining range for an array

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a problem defining a range on a separate sheet for an array that I have for a function that I'm running. The function is `KVLOOKUP` and can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24388978/looping-vlookup-style-function-with-separators). The problem I'm having is when I try to set the Range in `Sub Searched` it won't accept any type of defined range. I've tried what I can think of to define the range in different ways. Not sure where I'm going wrong here.

**Function to be Called**

```
Function KVLOOKUP(LookedValue As String, Matrix As Variant, Column As Integer) As Variant

 Dim Result() As Variant
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim Counter As Long
 Dim Column1 As Integer
 Column1 = Column + 1

 If IsObject(Matrix) Then Matrix = Matrix.Value
 On Error Resume Next
 Do
  i = i + 1
 Counter = UBound(Matrix, i)
 Loop Until Err.Number <> 0

 If Counter < Column Then KVLOOKUP = CVErr(xlErrNum): Exit Function
 Counter = 0

 For i = LBound(Matrix, 1) To UBound(Matrix, 1)
 If Matrix(i, 1) = LookedValue Then
 Counter = Counter + 1
 ReDim Preserve Result(1 To Counter)
 Result(Counter) = Matrix(i, Column) & " - " & Matrix(i, Column1)



 End If

 Next i

 On Error GoTo 0

 If Counter = 0 Then
    KVLOOKUP = CVErr(xlErrNA)
 Else
    KVLOOKUP = Result(1)
    For i = 2 To UBound(Result)
        KVLOOKUP = KVLOOKUP & ", " & Result(i)
    Next i
 End If
End Function
```

My problem is within the code below. In a cell I can call `KVLOOKUP` like a normal function `=KVLOOKUP(TextToSearch,'IDBHour1'!B2:E120,2)`. When I have attempted to define the same range by calling the function within VBA I haven't been able to define the same range as above.

**Sub to define E_name and Rnge Values**

For some reason if I try to define the range like this (which is how it would be done for a normal VLookup function) it doesn't provide any results. This is how I've been going about debugging my issue.

When I run the code I get an "Object variable or With Block variable not set" error

```
Sub SearcherBox()
'E_name is just a name i.e., John Doe
'Rnge is the range in which KVLOOKUP is searching for "John Doe"
 Dim Rnge as Range 
  Rnge = Sheets("IDBHour1").Range("B2:E120")
  Sal = Application.WorksheetFunction.KVLOOKUP(E_name, Rnge, 2)
   MsgBox Sal
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please narrow down your question just to problematic part (no need to post the entire code)? Thanks and regards,

Comment: *it won't accept any type of defined range*  What does thsi mean?  Do you get an error? If so, what is the error?

Comment: Also, it would be worth [advising you against](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) using `Selection.Value` **ESPECIALLY** when doing more advanced programming involving user forms, and multiple worksheets, etc...

Comment: @DavidZemens No data is returned at all. Even though the range that I'm trying to set for the array will work as a normal function within a cell on the sheet, when I try to achieve the same goal in VBA form it doesn't collect any results.

Comment: @AlexBell I've cleaned it up a bit. Hopefully you can understand what my issue is a little easier. Let me know if it's still not clear.

Comment: @ryano if you know that `Matrix` is a range, why are you defining it as a `variable`?

Comment: I think you cleaned up too much. Now we have no idea what actually transpires within your `KVLOOKUP` function.  When you debug this (you have debugged, right?) what are the value of `LookedValue`?  Is it what you expect it should be?  Same question for the other two arguments -- have you ensure to pass the correct arguments?   Also **GET RID OF ON ERROR RESUME NEXT** as that may be "hiding" the source of your problem.

Comment: @SilverShotBee Maybe I'm not understanding the question but I think it's because there's a problem in the original KVLOOKUP code if I change it to a range.

Comment: @DavidZemens Ok I've added JUST my debugging script. Using this method I haven't been able to successfully get any return values.

Comment: `Rnge` is an object variable. Object variables require using the `Set` keyword on assignment, so `SET Rnge = Sheets("IDBHour1").Range("B2:E120")` :)

Comment: @DavidZemens Ok, but now I'm getting an "Object doesn't support this property or method" error when I execute.

Comment: do I have to ask you again what line raises this new error?

Comment: @DavidZemens `Sal = Application.WorksheetFunction.KVLOOKUP(E_name, Rnge, 2)`

Comment: `KVLOOKUP` is not a `WorksheetFunction`...  call it simply like `Sal = KVLOOKUP(E_name, Rng, 2)`.

Comment: @DavidZemens Thanks for helping me through that I got it working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

`Rnge` is an object variable. Object variables require using the Set keyword on assignment, so

`SET Rnge = Sheets("IDBHour1").Range("B2:E120")`

Further, your UDF `KVLOOKUP` is not a WorksheetFunction and therefore not a member of the WOrksheetFunction class, so you get an error on the next line, too.  Call your UDF simply as:

```
Sal = KVLOOKUP(E_name, Rnge, 2)
```

Comment: I always forget to `SET` a range, that and `End If`... If `KVLOOKUP` is not a WorksheetFunction class, why are you telling the OP to call it like this `Sal = Application.WorksheetFunction.KVLOOKUP(E_name, Rnge, 2)`? (Just trying to understand if its a mistake, or if I'm being silly)